# Cannot run bind() with ldap3 in python3

Tags: python-3.x, ldap, connection, bind, ldap3

Below is my code to try and query my ldap server. However, for some reason, I cannot seem to make the bind command work to progress in my code. I continue to get the following message and am not sure what it means or how to fix it. I apologize about the error message formatting. I tried my best to make it as readable as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
>>> from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SUBTREE
>>> server = Server('<server_name>')
>>> conn = Connection(server, user='<username>', password='<password>')
>>> conn.open()
>>> conn.bind()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 427, in bind

```
response = self.post_send_single_response(self.send('bindRequest', request, controls))
```

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 122, in post_send_single_response

responses, result = self.get_response(message_id)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/base.py", line 298, in get_response

responses = self._get_response(message_id)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 168, in _get_response

dict_response = self.decode_response(ldap_resp)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/base.py", line 403, in decode_response

result = bind_response_to_dict(component)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/operation/bind.py", line 119, in bind_response_to_dict

'saslCreds': bytes(response['serverSaslCreds']) if response['serverSaslCreds'] is not None else None}

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 984, in **bytes**

return bytes(self._value)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 164, in plug

raise error.PyAsn1Error('Uninitialized ASN.1 value ("%s" attribute looked up)' % name)

pyasn1.error.PyAsn1Error: Uninitialized ASN.1 value ("**len**" attribute looked up)

Comment: Try to update ldap3 and pyasn1 to the latest version. The error should be related to changes in thee pyasn1 library.